# Free software to condense multiple images into pdf by folder?

Tags: windows, pdf, images, image-conversion

I have a list of folders, each containing a collection of images.

[image: Main folder with subfolders containing images]

[image: Subfolder with pictures]

I want to input the main directory and convert all images within each subfolder to a single pdf where the pdf is saved to its respective subfolder. To give a visual example

[image: Subfolder with PDF containing all images and name equal to subfolder]

What is the fastest and most efficient way to achieve this? I have tried multiple online sites and programs but they only work by folder or have a file limitation. Free software is preferred but anything that works is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

A popular CLI app you can use is [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php). All you do is execute this command in chosen directory:

```
magick dirname\* test.pdf
```

Which you can recurse for subdirectories with any kind of loop within your shell.

The more recommended tool thanks to quality and speed is [img2pdf](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf) though. The usage is quite similar:

```
img2pdf dirname\* --output test.pdf
```